# How to insert text, but not change the `.` do-again operation

Tags: vim

I am modifying a huge file with the same mod in many places. I know that I could use a macro, but actually using `.` do-again is easier for several reasons.

However, there is one place where I would like to make a small change, but I don't want to change what the `.` do-again key is doing. Is there a way to make this change without upsetting the operation of `.` do-again?

Alternatively, is there a way to store the operations of `.` in a register, and then restore from a register into `.`? Macros are just registers, so if I could store the contents of `.` in a register then I could probably run the macro once and then continue using `.` to rerun the macro.

Thanks!

Comment: `.` always performs the last change: it's not a register that you can edit. You should be a little more precise about what changes you are repeating with `.`, why you don't use macros or other mechanisms and what is the nature of the smallest changes you want to perform without breaking `.`.

Comment: Thanks, Romaint. I know that `.` is not a register but surely the keystrokes are stored somewhere. I do see the contents of the last insert under `.` when I run `:reg` but I cannot seem to copy them to another register.

Comment: `@.` and `.` are not the same thing: hitting `.` will repeat the last change, whatever it is (`~`, for example), while `@.` (which is read-only) only stores the last *inserted* text. If your changes only involves insertion you should probably use named registers.